# How to access getLoaderManager() inside a setOnItemClickListener() overriding an onItemClick()?

Tags: android, debugging, android-loadermanager, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

So I am stuck on how to access my getLoadManager from within that scope. All I really want to do is refresh the cursor since the LoaderManager is already created before it reaches that point, but I don't really now how to accomplish that besides calling getLoaderManager(). Problem is I can't in that scope. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

```
calendar.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*Stuff thats not really important to show*/

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use,

```
ActivityName.this.getLoaderManager();
```

Comment: I do have a quick question. When saying `this` in the normal scope of the class, is it the same as saying `ActivityName.this`?

Comment: Actually, I also have another question now that I was testing my code. About `getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, bundle, this)`. Lets assume that I want to use the same Loader inside of the above. But I want to provide a new Cursor. How can I accomplish this? When I do that again, it doesn't work. But when I provide a different ID, it works. And sorry with all the questions! I just like understanding thoroughly. In fact, if I keep clicking other dates, it doesn't update, I assume cuz its using the same cursor, but its not updated.

Comment: Yup. More specifically, `ActivityName.this` refers to the current instance of the `ActivityName` class. This is known as the [**qualified `this`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.8.4).

Comment: I doubt you want to pass `this` to `initLoader`. If you did, you'd be passing a reference to your anonymous class. The third argument to `initLoader` takes an object that has type `LoaderCallbacks<D>`. That being said, I would guess that you want to pass `ActivityName.this` instead (assuming `ActivityName implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`).